# How to implement Asp Identity in Clean Architecture with Asp net core

Tags: identity, clean-architecture

is there any code or docs about implement asp identity in clean architecture and how to apply CRUD operation in Application Layer with  User Entity that inherit from IdentityUser in Domain Layer 
I implement Asp identity in Domain Layer any ideas ??
I forget to mention that I use CQRS in Application layer

Answer (score 6):

[Here](https://fullstackmark.com/post/18/building-aspnet-core-web-apis-with-clean-architecture) is a nice article provinding a lot of information on how to implement a clean architecture using DDD TDD and Identity.

Hope it covers your needs.

Comment: thank you but I forget to mention that I dont use mapper or mediater so I have entity called user wich inherite from identitybase  that s all in domain layer so my question how I apply CQRS in Application Layer any exemple or sample code will be usefull